# Sed/Awk: Trigger when same pattern appears over multiple lines?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

Imagine having a text file. You want to know if in this file the same pattern (for example `<br>`) appears consecutively over N rows, you would want to delete the previous and the next 3 following lines. I guess I could figure out how to do this delete part, but I've got no idea how to implement this pattern magic.

Well for visualisation:

```
Foo <br>
Bar <br>
Baz <br>
<br>
```

Is a pattern that's mostly uniform in the file. But sometimes, there is stuff appearing that has to be removed in order for the file to be processed fine afterwards:

```
1 Not good Foo <br>
2 <br>
3 <br>
4 <br>
5 Dirt <br>
6 <br>
```

I added line numbers.

It's different to the not-tumorous pattern only because there are several breaks consecutively. So if we realize in line 3, this is a tumorous snippet, then we want to delete lines 1 to 6.

So, in conclusion:
Any time I see 2 `<br>` in a row, delete previous 2 lines, current line and next 3 lines.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102817/discussion-on-question-by-reisbrot-sed-awk-trigger-when-same-pattern-appears-ov).

Comment: Please edit your question to include a specific example of a "before" text and the corresponding "after" text to complement your description of the logic you want to use.  As written, it's extremely difficult to interpret what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your requirements correctly, you should get the results you want by opening the file in Vim and then typing:

```
:g/^<br>\n<br>$/-1,+4d
```

And then pressing "Enter".

You could also do this with `ex` if it has to be scripted.

---

Example:

Before:

```
Some line
Not good Foo <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Dirt <br>
<br>
Some additional line
```

After:

```
Some line
Some additional line
```